# Can't re-write Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: serial, arduino-pro-mini

I am just getting started with arduino, but I am having an issue with some 3.3V, 8Mhz Arduino Pro Minis. I am using a SparkFun FT232RL USB to Serial breakout (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12731) to communicate with the board, using Windows 7 and the Arduino IDE.

The Pro Minis were blank when I got them, I am able to upload a single program (Blink), which runs successfully, but I am unable to upload subsequent programs. I get the error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: How is the breakout connected to the Pro Mini?

Comment: Do you have auto reset hooked up?   If not and you are manually resetting, I found that activating verbose mode in the IDE makes the timing of pushing reset and hitting upload more forgiving.  Also make sure you have the correct baud rate for the upload, which might be different than for a 5v 16 MHz board.

Comment: The breakout is connected via Tx/Rx, GND, and VCC pins in the programming area at the edge of the pro mini. I have set the board to 3.3 8Mhz in the arduino IDE, i'll try hitting the manual reset again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect the DTR pin from the FT232 to the Promini as well, that will allow the software autoreset to work. Promini has a 0.1uF cap between the DTR pin and Reset already.